# Strange alignment of rendered text in a code chunk

Tags: support

In an [answer of mine on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70529/1390) I have the following code chunk, indicated via indentation by 4 spaces at the start of the line.

```
> AIC(gam_example$lme)
[1] -2.136317
> AIC(gamm_example$lme)
[1] -1286.448
```

(Note that to illustrate this I have wrapped the above in HTML `<pre>` tags - the layout above is how it was entered in the edit window in the Answer.)

The displayed code block is rendered as

```
> AIC(gam_example$lme)
    [1] -2.136317
    > AIC(gamm_example$lme)
[1] -1286.448
```

(Again, here this is wrapped in `<pre>` in the editor, but only to show the problem.)

Clearly the alignment in the code block is wrong. I wonder if this is something to do with MathJax (note the `$` in both chunks). Compare these two blocks, both entered without `<pre>` tags in the editor:

```
> AIC(gam_example$lme)
[1] -2.136317
> AIC(gamm_example$lme)
[1] -1286.44
```

and

```
> AIC(gam_example$lme)
[1] -2.136317
> AIC(gamm_example)
[1] -1286.44
```

The first chunk of these two is a live example of the problem I report here. Note the lack of a second `$` in the second code block allows this to render with the correct, intended alignment.

Is there anything that can be done about this, or is it an unfortunate clash of R syntax and MathJax? Or something else?

Comment: @smillig *sigh*, I thought I'd done my due diligence and checked related Qs. Thanks for doing that job properly for me and pointing out the original. I've voted to close. (+1)

Comment: ... and I actually answered that duplicate and had forgotten it existed.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it looks like a clash of markup procedures. The only workaround I have found is to add a comment containing an odd number of $\$$ after each offending line.  For example,

```
> AIC(gam_example$lme)
    [1] -2.136317
    > AIC(gamm_example$lme)
[1] -1286.44
```

becomes

```
> AIC(gam_example$lme) #$
[1] -2.136317
> AIC(gamm_example$lme) #$
[1] -1286.44
```

Comment: Thanks; I supposed one could also render using `<pre>`, as I did above, but that begs the question why this fails for the rendered code blocks and not for code added in `<pre>` tags. This seems to be something specific to code blocks and how they are rendered from the MD into HTML.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. I've run into this problem many times and sometimes managed to get it to go away, but this is a better solution than any I managed.