# Render `pre` tags in same style as code blocks in CSS

Tags: feature-request, design

I [recently came across](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1792/1390) the niggle of odd formatting of code chunks when the code chunk includes R syntax with a number of `$` characters. @whuber [has suggested a workaround](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1793/1390) that involves adding an extra `$` in a comment, which resolves the problem.

As my question showed, the problem doesn't arise if one explicitly marks the block up with `<pre>...</pre>` tags, presumably because the chunk is included verbatim and not rendered by the Markdown (MD) processor. However, there are subtle differences in styling of blocks marked up  with `<pre>...</pre>` tags and those marked as code chunks in MD. The latter are rendered as `<pre><code>....</code></pre>`.

Is it possible to tweak the CSS here to render plain `<pre>....</pre>` marked sections with the same styles as `<pre><code>....</code></pre>`? That would make using this as a work around less noticeable but not require the user to remember to nest `<code>` within `<pre>` to get the required styling?

#### Example

First a standard code block indicated using MD

```
foo <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
summary(foo)
```

Next a chunk entered as verbatim HTML via `<pre>...</pre>` tags only

```
foo <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
summary(foo)
```

Finally, a chunk entered verbatim but wrapped in `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`

```
foo <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
summary(foo)
```

Notice the subtle styling differences in sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, scratch that.

Adding `<pre>` tags just makes this worse as unless you encode html entities like `<` which is much more of a pain for R code than adding a comment and an extra `$`. I'll leave this open for a wee while to see if anyone has anything else to suggest/contribute, but otherwise I should probably close or delete this as appropriate.